# Salesforce CPQ - Quote Lines, Quote Line Groups, and MDQ - Visualforce Approval Email Template

Tags: apex, email-template, visualforce-component, cpq

Our team is looking to launch MDQ for our products in CPQ, however while this is handled seamlessly on the Quote Template end, I am struggling to make an Approval Email Template that will adequately display this data for approval to leadership.

I have scoured the web and came up empty for finding any examples of how this can be handled on the approval email template side.

Been looking into the CPQ Managed Visualforce Components as that seemed like a good way to keep things aligned with Quote Documents.

[image: CPQ Visualforce Managed Components]

Unfortunately the only documentation I have found around any of these is within Component Reference:
[image: Visualforce Component Documentation]

I'm not even positive these can be used with email as it "Generates XSL-FO tree for the section that contains line items." I've been able to get Quote Lines and Quote Line Groups to at least generate in a sorted fashion using the Visualforce Component below, but I am at a total loss for the MDQ side of things. Hoping someone on here has run into this before and has some recommendations or guidance!

```
    <apex:component controller="QuoteApprovalsCmpController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="cmpQuoteId" type="String" description="ID of the Quote" required="required" assignTo="{!quoteId}"/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!groupedQuoteLines}" var="groupedLine">
        <h3>{!groupedLine.groupName}</h3>
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #6EC0EE; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>Product Name</b></td>
                <td style="background-color: #6EC0EE; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:right;"><b>Unit Price</b></td>
                <td style="background-color: #6EC0EE; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:center;"><b>Quantity</b></td>
                <td style="background-color: #6EC0EE; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:right;"><b>Total Price</b></td>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!groupedLine.quoteLines}" var="lineItem">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!lineItem.SBQQ__ProductName__c}</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;"><apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}"><apex:param value="{!lineItem.SBQQ__ListPrice__c}" /></apex:outputText></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;"><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,###}"><apex:param value="{!lineItem.SBQQ__Quantity__c}"/></apex:outputText></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;"><apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}"><apex:param value="{!lineItem.SBQQ__NetTotal__c}" /></apex:outputText></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

[image: Quote Line Groups]

Any help is much appreciated!